# How to disable htmlspecialchars in custom module form table?

Tags: 8, forms

I'm making a table form

```
$form['table'] = [
  '#type' => 'tableselect',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#options' => $this->getOutput(),
  '#empty' => t('No vehicles found'),
];
```

In `getOutput()` I have `'vehicleName' =>  "<a href=\"/vehicle?id=" . $vehicle->vehicleId . "\">"  . $vehicle->vehicleName . "</a>",` for one of the fields. And it doesn't print out as normal html. It goes through `htmlspecialchars()` and I don't have clickable link at the end. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FormattableMarkup`

Here's a simple example to get you started

```
use Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup; // place this at top of file

$options = [
  1 => ['foo' => 'Foo'],
  2 => ['foo' => 'Bar'],
  3 => ['foo' => new FormattableMarkup('<a href="http://example.com">I am a link</a>', [])],
];

$header = [
  'foo' => t('Foo bar')
];

$form['table'] = [
  '#type' => 'tableselect',
  '#title' => t('Foo bar table'),
  '#header' => $header,
  '#options' => $options,
  '#empty' => t('No foos found.'),
];
```

So in your case `$this->getOutput()` may return something like (this is untested):

```
['vehicleName' =>  new FormattableMarkup(
  '<a href="/vehicle?id=@id">@name</a>', 
  ['@id' => $vehicle->vehicleId, '@name' => $vehicle->vehicleName]
)]
```